# How do I make a conditional calculation to search a record field for a specific string?

Tags: scripting, filemaker

I have two fields: `Description` and `Type`.

When the `Description` field contains the string "Beneficiary" amongst other words, I would like the field Type to automatically set as "Beneficiary"

So the calculation I have come up with is:

```
If ( Descrizione= "BENEFICIARI" ; Type = "Beneficiary")
```

The problem is, Filemaker only searches the entire text and not just an individual string, is there any function I can use to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Most commonly, you would use either the [PatternCount function](http://www.filemaker.com/help/html/func_ref3.33.73.html) to see if a description contains a word or the [Position function](http://www.filemaker.com/12help/html/func_ref3.33.78.html) to do a calculation like this.

#### Position Function

The [Position function](http://www.filemaker.com/12help/html/func_ref3.33.78.html) returns the position of the first character of the matching substring (or 0 if the substring is not found.) As Sam points out in the comments, this function should return a value faster than the PatternCount function. It takes four arguments:

1. the text to search
2. what substring to search for
3. the starting position of the search, and
4. which occurrence of the substring to show the position of

Assuming that your Type field is a text field with an auto-enter Calculated Value, you could use this formula:

```
If ( Position ( Descrizione ; "BENEFICIARI" ; 1 ; 1 ) ; "Beneficiary" )
```

#### PatternCount Function

The [PatternCount function](http://www.filemaker.com/help/html/func_ref3.33.73.html) returns the number of instances of the substring that are found within a string. It takes two arguments:

1. the text to search
2. the substring to search for

Assuming that your Type field is a text field with an auto-enter Calculated Value, you could use this formula:

```
If ( PatternCount ( Descrizione ; "BENEFICIARI" ) ; "Beneficiary" )
```

In the above, if the PatternCount is True (1 or more occurrences), "Beneficiary" will be returned.

Comment: Position is preferable for this, as it stops scanning the description once it finds the first occurrence. Minor performance gain.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `PatternCount` function to search for a particular string within a larger string.  So, your formula might look like this:

`If ( PatternCount ( Descrizione ; "beneficiari" ) ; "Beneficiary" )`

Note that the `PatternCount` function is NOT case sensitive (which is why I put it in all lower case, for illustration purposes).